# GridSearchCV on ExtremelyFastDecisionTreeClassifier() isn't working (skmultiflow)

Tags: python, classification, data-mining, decision-tree, gridsearchcv

i looking for help to execute GridSearchCV on the hyperparametres of my EDFT classifier. i got an error and don't find any ressource on the web or an effective answer by chatGPT... so i'm here.

here is my error : **"ValueError: The key pairwise is not defined in _get_tags() for the class ExtremelyFastDecisionTreeClassifier." **

the error appear here

```
efdt_tuned.fit(X, y)
```

just note that it is my first EFDT so maybe it's just obvious. And i fill params more or less randomly (https://scikit-multiflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/skmultiflow.trees.ExtremelyFastDecisionTreeClassifier.html) but whatever i change the same error appear.

Just as info i got a EFDT who works and get 52% accuracy (I presume it's trash). so i wanted to try GridSearchCV to improve it.

here is my code full code :

```
# Split the data into features and target
numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=['float', 'int']).columns
X = df[numeric_columns]
y = df['PTS']
y = pd.DataFrame(y)
y['PTS'] = pd.to_numeric(y['PTS'])

# Preprocessing
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
selector = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=10)
X = selector.fit_transform(X, y)

# Create a DataStream object from the features and target
stream = DataStream(X, y)

# Hyperparameter tuning
params = {
    'split_criterion': ['gini', 'entropy', 'misclassification'],
    'split_confidence': [0.01, 0.05, 0.1],
    'tie_threshold': [0.05, 0.1, 0.15],
    'grace_period': [50, 100, 200],
    'max_byte_size': [1000000, 2000000, 3000000],
    'memory_estimate_period': [10000, 100000, 1000000],
    'leaf_prediction': ['mc', 'nb', 'nba']
}

efdt_tuned = GridSearchCV(ExtremelyFastDecisionTreeClassifier(),
                          param_grid=params,
                          scoring='accuracy',
                          n_jobs=-1,
                          cv=5)

# Fit the GridSearchCV object with the training data
efdt_tuned.fit(X, y)

# Setup variables to control loop and track performance
n_samples = 0
correct_cnt = 0
max_samples = 200

# Train the estimator with the samples provided by the data stream
while n_samples < max_samples and stream.has_more_samples():
    X, y = stream.next_sample()

    # Predict using the fitted GridSearchCV object
    y_pred = efdt_tuned.predict(X)

    if y[0] == y_pred[0]:
        correct_cnt += 1
    efdt_tuned.partial_fit(X, y)
    n_samples += 1

# Display results
print('{} samples analyzed.'.format(n_samples))
print('Extremely Fast Decision Tree accuracy: {}'.format(correct_cnt / n_samples))
```

thank you a lot for your time.
sorry for my english i try my best as french speaker ...

I hope someone can help me fix my error and so be able to optimize my EFDT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be in the ExtremelyFastDecisionTreeClassifier variable

You have to see have the correct labels `_get_tags` is correctly connected to the class `ExtremelyFastDecisionTreeClassifier`. Add value `_more_tags` you should be able to use the GridSearchCV with the `ExtremelyFastDecisionTreeClassifier` class without errors.

Comment: Thank you. as i say i never experienced this kind of things before. can you show me how to connect the correct lables _get_tags_ to my EFDT ?

Comment: class ExtremelyFastDecisionTreeClassifier(BaseSKMObject):
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize your classifier
        pass
    
    def partial_fit(self, X, y):
        # add your partial_fit method here
        pass
    
    def predict(self, X):
        # add your predict method here
        pass
    
    def _more_tags(self):
        return {'multioutput': False, 'multioutput_only': False}